# Установка Windows поверх Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

Как установить Windows 7 на ноутбук с уже установленной Ubuntu, чтобы можно было загрузить и Линукс, и Винду?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. На тот же HDD, или на отдельный?

Comment: На тот же HDD.

Comment: спокойно ставим а потом изменяем груб

Answer (score 2):

Если Windows ставится на отдельный раздел, то нам необходимо будет восстановить затертый GRUB:

1. Создать Live USB с Ubuntu: [способ №1](http://voffa.ru/useful/ubuntu-live-flash-stick-windows.html) или [способ №2](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/создание_live_системы_на_usb_устройствах)
2. Установить Windows
3. Загрузится с ранее созданного Live USB
4. В терминале выполнить след. команды: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update` и `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`
5. Перезагрузить машину

Comment: а винда потом грузиться будет?

Comment: Если в Лине потом сделать sudo update-grubто вендовый раздел он найдёт, и венда грузиться будет!

Answer (score 0):

Как я помню, то Windows устанавливается на разделы NTFS (без учета хисториокон)... Если, что изменилось, напишите! С п.2 и далее я солидарен с [uzumaxy](http://admin.hashcode.ru/users/1662/uzumaxy)

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того, вот здесь стоит посмотреть: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ Там есть средство для мультисистемной загрузки, и много ещё чего...